# Edit a Hash contained in another Hash

Tags: ruby, dictionary, hashmap

I have a Hash inside a Hash with the following structure:

```
mysystem = {
  "slicompany" => {
    "sahil" => "developer",
    "Jag" => "developer"
  },
  "uzanto" => {
    "kapil" => "tech lead"
  }
}
```

What is the best way to add/delete/edit the elements of the inner Hashes?

Comment: `mysystem['slicompany']['sahil'] = 'tech lead'`

Comment: Cool! Im curious, is there any other way than this?

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html

Comment: Why would you need another way. Accessing a Hash using keys is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

As Uri Agassi says it's very easy to access nested hashes via keys...

```
mysystem['slicompany']['sahil'] = 'tech lead'
```

For convenience, you can also assign the inner hash to a separate variable, changes to that variable will be reflected in the "outer" variable (since the inner variable and the hash of the outer variable are pointing to the same hash object)

```
slicompany = mysystem['slicompany']

slicompany["George"] = "dishwasher"

p mysystem
=> {"slicompany" => {"sahil" => "developer", "Jag" => "developer", "George" => "dishwasher"},
  "uzanto" => {"kapil" => "tech lead"}}
```